# scp fails with "FIPS_mode_set:fingerprint does not match" error

Tags: linux, ssh, openssl, scp, fips

I have the following machine:

```
Linux ssim-21416 2.6.18-348.3.1.el5 #1 SMP Mon Mar 11 19:39:25 EDT 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

and

```
CentOS release 5.9 (Final)
```

now when i try to do scp or ssh it fails with the following error:

```
7477:error:2D06C06E:FIPS routines:FIPS_mode_set:fingerprint does not match:fips.c:493:
lost connection
```

following openssl rpm is installed on my machine:

```
openssl-0.9.8e-26.el5_9.1
```

following fips rpms are installed

```
fipscheck-lib-1.2.0-1.el5
fipscheck-1.2.0-1.el5
```

Please could someone help me to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

> when i try to do scp or ssh it fails with the following error...

This is going to be difficult for me to help with because I don't know Red Hat or CentOS. But I do understand OpenSSL and its FIPS process, so I give you one suggestion that should work. But it takes more work on your part.

Download and build `scp` and `ssh` yourself. However, when you do, perform the following:

```
$ export CC=`find /usr/local -name fipsld`
$ echo $CC 
$ /usr/local/ssl/fips-2.0/bin/fipsld
$ export FIPSLD_CC=`find /usr/bin -name gcc`
$ echo $FIPSLD_CC 
/usr/bin/gcc
```

Now, do a standard `config` and `make`. Sometimes you have to do `config`, then adjust `CC` and `FIPSLD_CC`, and then run make.

Install them is `/usr/local/bin` and use them from there.

---

If you need to build the OpenSSL FIPS Object Module and FIPS Capable Library from sources, then:

```
# Build the FIPS Object Module
$ tar xzf openssl-fips-2.0.5.tar.gz
$ cd openssl-fips-2.0.5
$ ./config
$ make
$ sudo make install

# Build the FIPS Capable Library
$ tar xzf openssl-1.0.1f.tar.gz
$ cd openssl-1.0.1f
$ ./config fips <other options you like>
$ make all
$ sudo make install
```

Be sure to use a tool that operates in FIPS mode to verify the signature on the download. If yo don't have such a tool, you will have to order a CD from the OpenSSL Foundation.